# Javascript draw a quote again if it's longer than x

Tags: javascript

I have this code which connects to an API and draws a random quote from it.

I want to create an if statement which checks if the quotes length is lower or equal to 140 and returns it, or draws again if its longer but I don't have an idea on how to start.

```
request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", "https://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=20", false);
request.send(); 
request = [].slice.call(JSON.parse(request.response));

var button = document.getElementById("button");
var authorname = document.getElementById("authorname");
var quotetext = document.getElementById("quotetext");
var drawnquote = request[Math.floor(Math.random() * request.length)].content;

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  quotetext.innerHTML = request[Math.floor(Math.random() * request.length)].content;
  authorname.innerHTML = request[Math.floor(Math.random() * request.length)].title;  
});
```

What I came up is:

```
button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (drawnquote.length <= 140){
  quotetext.innerHTML = drawnquote;
  } else {

});
```

^ And this is where my ideas end. Could anyone point me to a proper direction or give advice? Thanks!

PS: If possibile, I'm trying to use vanilla js.

Comment: Creating a line-break in the middle of a string in JavaScript is not legal.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl but I just want to check if the quote I've drawn from the API is longer than 140 characters and place it in the 'quotetext' div. If it's longer, I want it to be redrawn until a quote shorter than 140 characters appears.

But maybe I misundertood what you wrote ( I'm a newbie ).

Comment: A line break between lines 2 and 3 is illegal in JS. I will fix your post to show you what mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The central problem here is branching with asynchronous code, which can be tricky.  I see you're also getting a batch of quotes (20 in your example).  That's a good idea, but what if the 20 quotes you get back all exceed 140 characters?  We'll start out only fetching one, and then I'll show you how to make it more efficient by fetching multiple ones.  You're also not using `XHTMLHttpRequest` correctly...you're using it as if it operated synchronously, which it doesn't.  You have to add an event listener to process the response.  Here's a correct implementation to get a single quote, functionalized:

```
function getQuote(maxLength, cb) {
  const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.addEventListener('load', function() {
    const resp = JSON.parse(this.responseText)
    cb(resp[0].content)
  })
  request.open("GET", "https://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?" 
    + "filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1", false);
  request.send(); 
}
```

As an editorial note, I would probably do this with promises, but since I'm not sure if promises are available to you, I'm just using callbacks.

This will get a single quote, regardless of length.  You would use it like this:

```
getQuote(140, function(quote) {
  console.log(quote)
})
```

Now let's consider the problem of getting another quote if the first one is too long.  Because Ajax is async, you can't just write a loop.  The easiest way to make this happen in this case is to make the function recursive:

```
function getQuote(maxLength, cb) {
  const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.addEventListener('load', function() {
    // note that we're stripping out HTML -- probably don't want
    // to include that in the length
    const quote = JSON.parse(this.responseText)[0].content
      .replace(/<[^>]+\/>/g, '')
      .trim()
    // if it doesn't match our length requirements,
    // recursively call the function again
    if(quote.length > maxLength) return getQuote(maxLength, cb)
    cb(quote)
  })
  request.open("GET", "https://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?"
    + "filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1", false);
  request.send(); 
}
```

So far so good...problem is, every time I run this, I get a "Maximum call stack size exceeded" exception.  That means it's cycling through 16,000-some quotes, and they're all greater than 140.  So what you're doing may be a fool's errand.  However, we can look through 320,000 quotes instead by getting more quotes per request:

```
function getQuote(maxLength, cb) {
  const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.addEventListener('load', function() {
    const quotes = JSON.parse(this.responseText)
    for(let quote of quotes) {
      quote = JSON.parse(this.responseText)[0].content
        .replace(/<[^>]+\/>/g, '')
        .trim()
      // we found a short quote!
      if(quote.length <= maxLength) return cb(quote)
    }
    // we didn't! have to recursively call the function again
    return getQuote(maxLength, cb)
  })
  request.open("GET", "https://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?"
    + "filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=20", false);
  request.send(); 
}
```

Even with this, I exceeded the maximum call stack size.  So it looks like this particular database just doesn't have very many (or any) quotes less than 140 characters...but at least you now have a template for the algorithm.

Comment: Wow, thank you for the long post and detailed explanation!

Answer (score 0):

When you send a request, the response does not immediately appear in the next statement as you have it:

```
request.send(); 
request.response // will not necessarily be set
```

When you `send()` a request, it's success will eventually trigger a 'load' event. You need to specify an even listener to be called when the load event is fired, before you call `send()`:

```
request.addEventListener('load', function onLoad () {
    console.log(this.responseText); 
});
```

See more examples at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest